PowerShell array param with optional values
I'd like my PS script to have an interface like this:
tool.ps1 -Update item1, item2, item3 # Update individual items
tool.ps1 -Update # Update all items

I've tried all known attribute combinations (AllowEmptyCollection etc), and still can't get the second example to work: PS asks to provide a param value.
Any ideas?

Without showing the script, there is not much to help you with...

You can achieve the described behavior by separating the -Update parameter from the optional arguments:
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Default')]
param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Update')]
  [switch]$Update,

  [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true, DontShow = $true)]
  [string[]]$Values
)

if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Update') {
  # update requested
  if ($Values.Count) {
    Write-Host "Updating items: $($Values -join ', ')"
  }
  else {
    Write-Host "Updating all items!"
  }
}
else {
  Write-Host "No update requested"
}

Now, if present, the additional arguments will be bound to the hidden -Values parameter instead (thanks to the ValuesFromRemainingArguments flag), which should give you the behavior you want:
PS ~> .\tool.ps1 -Update
Updating all items!
PS ~> .\tool.ps1 -Update item1, item2, item3
Updating items: item1, item2, item3
PS ~> .\tool.ps1
No update requested


Aren't Switch parameters Not Suggested to be Mandatory?

@sirtao You definitely shouldn't mark it mandatory if it's associated with the default parameter set :)

@MathiasR.Jessen it makes sense, thanks

An alternative to Mathias' solution, using Dynamic Parameters.
This way -UpdateValues exists only if -Update is specified, so it doesn't appeat in autosuggestion otherwise but does once -Update is input.
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'Default')]
param(
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Update')]
    [switch]$Update
)
dynamicparam {
    if ($Update.IsPresent) {
        $parameterAttribute = [System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute]@{
            ParameterSetName            = 'Update'
            Mandatory                   = $false
            ValueFromRemainingArguments = $true
            HelpMessage = "Values to update"

        }
        $attributeCollection = [System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]]::new()
        $attributeCollection.Add($parameterAttribute)
        $dynParam1 = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter]::new(
            'UpdateValues', [string[]], $attributeCollection
        )
        $paramDictionary = [System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary]::new()
        $paramDictionary.Add('UpdateValues', $dynParam1)
        return $paramDictionary
    }
}

process {
    # if -Update is called.   
    if ($Update.IsPresent) {
        # if -Value is called, even implicitly by the remaining arguments.   
        if ($PSBoundParameters.UpdateValues) {
            Write-Host "Updating items: $($PSBoundParameters.UpdateValues -join ', ')"
        }
        # if -Values is not called
        else {
            Write-Host 'Updating all items!'
        }
    }
    # if -Update is not called.   
    else {
        Write-Host 'No update requested'
    }
}

and here some examples of it being called
PS ~> .\test.ps1
No update requested

PS ~> .\test.ps1 -Update
Updating all items!

PS ~> .\test.ps1 -Update -UpdateValues 1,2,3  
Updating items: 1, 2, 3

PS ~> .\test.ps1 -Update a,b,c
Updating items: a, b, c

PS ~> .\test.ps1 -UpdateValues 1,2,3        
test.ps1: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'UpdateValues'.

